# jquery cross-browser supports issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I came to know that [jquery supports all including old browsers](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

But I tried to add a placeholder for search box and it is not working in IE8

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').attr('placeholder','search....');                          
});
```

So I want to know more about cross-browser supports. As said does it work actually or not?

---

I know the html attribute `placeholder` is not supported. But my question is about with jquery.

Comment: IE8 ?? Kill it with fire !! :p

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-tag-in-ie8-and-9)? It seems like a duplicate question has been asked before...

Comment: You seem to be abusing the placeholder attribute as a substitute for a `<label>` element. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) forbids that.

Comment: I seem to be suppose that jquery uses its own definition beyond the html but having this question came to know jquery just parse the dom......

Answer (score 2):

placeholder is an HTML5 feature which is not supported by IE8

use the following

```
<input type="text" value="search..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'search...') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'search...';" />
```

using jquery

```
<input type="text" class="my-input" value=""  />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.my-input').val('search...');
            $('.my-input').focus(function () {
                if (this.value == 'search...') this.value = '';
            });
            $('input.my-input').blur(function () {
                if (this.value == '') this.value = 'search...'
            });
        });
        /*
        here I assumed a class
        .my-input 

        you can use input#id or input.className or other selector

        better you give the code of your text-box or entire form so that I can give you the exact selector

        */
    </script>
```

Comment: how can I do the same with jquery coz I can't edit the markup

Answer (score 1):

As Above Placeholder is not supported.
So add the following code/comments to the head of your HTML page. And now ie8 will play nicely.

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: what is HTML5 Shim and Respond.js ? please discuss briefly about HTML5 Shim and Respond.js and when this 2 is required? thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE8 dosen't support placeholders

only IE10+ supports to this attribute

But if you really want to have placeholders take a look at this jQuery plugin https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not JQuery but the placeholder attribute itself. See [this chart](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder) for an answer to your question : **No**, IE8 does not support the [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute).