# In a Wordpress theme (using get_search_form()), how can I add placeholder text to the search box?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a theme and I am displaying a search box in the header using:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Is there a way that I can get placeholder text to show in that box?

Comment: related docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/

Answer (score 18):

I ended up figuring out that if I don't have a file called "searchform.php" in my theme folder, Wordpress displays is default form that doesn't include any placeholder text:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I created a new file called "searchform.php" in my theme folder and modified the default form to include the placeholder text:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search gear, clothing, & more.." />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

make searchform.php in theme folder and place that code in it

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<div>
<input class="text" type="text" value=" " name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" class="submit button" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Search');?>" />
</div>
</form>
```

Change whatever you want ! like class,placeholder,text any thing you want but not change like name, id and form attribute

Thanks

Comment: Nice! Didn't know this way. Thanks, @Vishal!

Answer (score 2):

The WP codex has an [example with a placeholder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Examples):

> If your theme supports HTML5, which happens if it uses
>   `add_theme_support('html5', array('search-form'))`, it will output the
>   following HTML form. This is the case since WordPress 3.6.

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

If you don't want to use HTML5 tags and attributes, you can [create placeholders with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/).

Answer (score 1):

The [official get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) explained the more flexible modified that could add in your funtions.php.

check out here with [CodeX commit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/#user-contributed-notes).

### TL;DR

Checkout the code below.

```php
function wpdocs_my_search_form( $form ) {
// replace the new form on your own.
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
 
    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpdocs_my_search_form' );
```