# Text used in placeholders becomes search word when nothing is inputted in search box- only in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, placeholder

There a lot of issues concerning `placeholder` and IE8 or IE9. 
But i haven't or maybe haven't look too much for the answer for my placeholder problem. 
I was able to use placeholder but the problem is when I use IE8 browser, the text use as placeholder will become the searched word if I will not type anything on the search box. The placeholder is working though like when i click the search box, the text will disappear.
Only during searching is my problem. It treats the placeholder text as the searched word.
By the way, i just want to use pure javascript if possible.

Does any have work around for this issue?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is this problem specific to IE 8/9? Have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: If i'm correct, html5 placeholder not officialy supported by ie8. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-tag-in-ie8-and-9

Comment: yes, the problem appears only in IE8/9. okay, i'll look into it