# Input text set a default value which shoud be removed when click to enter my text

Tags: html

I have an input text, I wanna set a default value on it and when I click to enter my text.
The default value must be removed.  how to do that.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. If the default value should be removed if the user thinks about changing it, then it is a terrible default. Maybe you want a placeholder or a label instead (keeping in mind that they are [not interchangeable](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a placeholder:

```
<input placeholder="Write something here..."/>
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpJ7f/)</kbd>

Comment: placeHolder is not supported by IE 8 and 7 :(

Comment: You could look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-tag-in-ie8-and-9