# Change placeholder text based on the dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I have a selectbox with couple of options to be selected by the user, when the user selects "First Name ", I want to the placeholder text 'Enter your First Name' to be appear beside the textbox.
please find my piece of my code below:

HTML:

```
<select id="selectionType">
<option value="-1">Select One</option>
<option value="0">First Name</option>
<option value="1">Last Name</option>
```

JS:

```
    var placeholderText = {"First Name":"Enter your First Name","Last Name":"Enter your Last Name"};

$("#selectionType").on("change",function() {
    var selection = document.getElementById("selectionType");
    var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");

    var selectedVal = $('#selectionType').find(':selected').text();
    if (placeholderText[selectedVal] !== undefined) {
        inputBox.placeholder = placeholderText[selectedVal];
    }
});
```

It works fine in Chrome and FF, but it fails in IE 8 & 9...
Any help on this.

See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sW6QP/6/

Comment: IE 8,9 DO NOT support placeholders. **[Check this for a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15020826/3639582)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to support in IE 8 & 9.

because IE 8 and 9 don't support html5 placeholder and only support in IE 10.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: I will use a jquery library for placeholder to get it work...thanks

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 var placeholderText = {
    "First Name": "Enter your First Name",
    "Last Name": "Enter your Last Name"
};

$("#selectionType").on("change", function () {

    if (this.value != -1) {
        $("#inputBox").val(placeholderText[$("#selectionType option:selected").text()]);
    } else {
        $("#inputBox").val("");
    }

});
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sW6QP/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your brand new code:

```
var placeholderText = {"First Name":"Enter your First Name","Last Name":"Enter your Last Name"};
$("#selectionType").on("change",function() {
    var selection = $("#selectionType");
    var inputBox = $("#inputBox");

    var selectedVal = $(':selected', selection).text();
    if (placeholderText[selectedVal] !== undefined) {
        inputBox..attr('placeholder', placeholderText[selectedVal]);
    }
});
```

It should solve your problem