# Placeholder not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have used the place holder function in textboxes as a watermark in my form. But the problem is that, the same thing is not working in IE 8 browser. I cant see the watermark text in IE 8 browser.

Please see my asp code, as I have used.

HTML :-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="txtFldName" placeholder="Enter your Full Name"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript for the the placeholder:-

```
<script src="../js/jquery.placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input', 'txtFirstName').placeholder();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `txtAccountNumber` is there. The second parameter usually means "context", a reference to an element from which the selector should start looking for an element. Try removing that.

Comment: I am sorry added the wrong parameter. will try removing the parameter

Comment: @RahulSutar Check if `asp:TextBox` is an `input` or a `textarea`.

Comment: its input only. It works for the first time, but when I focus out and then focusIn, it stops working

Answer (score 0):

I think placeholder works only in IE10+

Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: it works dude in IE 8 also, just need to be more specific on how to use it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-attribute-in-ie8-and-9

Comment: So is there any other way to use watermark which supports IE8 also ?

Comment: I think only with JS/jquery