# Jquery water mark issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used a Jquery watermark to display text in the textboxes. The problem is that, when I fill the data in textboxes and without  checking the terms and conditions checbox. The value in the textbox gets disappeared and the watermark text again comes. But when I click on the textbox again, the same value i can see. How is it happening. Please see my jquery code and HTMl for your reference:

```
<script src="../js/WaterMark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=txtFirstName]").WaterMark();
    });
  </script>
```

HTML for the watermark:-

```
<tr>
 <td class="tdColName">Full Name<span style="color: #CF060D;">*</span></td>
 <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="txtFldName" ToolTip="Enter Your Full Name"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Namskar Rahul Bhau make JSFidderl na :)

Comment: hi Amy, check the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4k8chh/1/

Comment: Why you are not using placeholder attribute?

Comment: i am using in asp.net, and I used tooltip. but to show u in jsfiddle I changed it into the html textbox.

Comment: Try this once: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtFldName" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Tooltip is for showing hind on Mouseover.

Comment: but placeholder property is not working in IE8

Comment: See This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-attribute-in-ie8-and-9

Comment: can you give an example of this how to use it. As I have already tried using this.But I wasn't able to implement.Please Amy

Comment: Just import given JQuery library and follow the given steps in GitHub

Comment: Open this in IE8: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Comment: @Amy: I already opened that link in IE8, u just explain me the steps. Coz I am not getting the exact steps. Just create the JS fiddle for atelast one Input and let me know.

Comment: Ok will make it for you. It will take time, I will let you know when its done.

Comment: sure, i will wait..Thanks in advance

Comment: I Just posted the answer refer this

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Name';}">
```

Comment: for using it in asp.net, can I change input type to asp control ? And also, is there any js plugins associated with ?

Comment: I dont have any idea about asp.

Comment: and what about plugins ? any plugins associated with it

Comment: where is onBlur and onFocus function is written ?

Comment: I don't able to get your exact requirement sorry

Answer (score 0):

Using the following jQuery plugin,You can create

http://digitalbush.com/files/jquery/watermarkinput/beta1/jquery.watermarkinput.js

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName"  />
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("#txtFirstName").Watermark("Enter Your Name");
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuzrc4og/)

Comment: hii, can you also add a button and adding data and submit it and then again click on the textbox. there's some serious issue

Comment: @RahulSutar Have you include jquery.js?

Comment: Have you check the fiddle demo? is that not your requirement?

Comment: yes I checked that as well, but still it is not working