# jQuery on focus on blur with an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

** This is not a duplication of any IE9 Placeholder issues. The reason being, the old JSP framework I use which is WebWork doesnt support placeholders in the HTML. **

**What I want to do**

I want to show a value in the field as `placeholder` text. But if the user starts typing, the placeholder text should disappear.

**Problem**

If I type something and click outside, what I typed gets replaced with the placeholder text. I want to stop it from being replaced. If the input is empty, show the placeholder text, if the input has a value, don't replace the text.

**Restriction**

I also cant use `placeholder` attribute for some technical reasons. (old framework and needs to support IE9).

Hope you guys can help.

```
var inputTextIDs = [
    [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
    ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location2"]
];

$.each(inputTextIDs, function(i, v) {
    //$('input'+inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
    $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).on('change', function() {
        var inputValue = $.trim($('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val());
        $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
        $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).on('focus', function() {
            $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val('');
        }).on('blur', function() {
            $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think we can't stop from replacing placeholder while typing !!

Comment: @nasty you can check my answer as per you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-attribute-in-ie8-and-9 and many others.

Comment: @freedomn-m No its not a duplication. I cannot use that placeholder plugin becuase im using WebWork, an old JSP framework and this has plugin complications.

Comment: Maybe not, but the linked questions have over 10 code based solutions that are almost identical to the answers given here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location2"]

];

$.each(inputTextIDs, function(i, v) {

  $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).on('focus', function() {
    if ($('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val() == inputTextIDs[i][1]) {
      $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val('');
    }
  }).on('blur', function() {
    if (!$('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val()) {
      $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
    }
  });


  $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hotelLocaiton" />
<input id="agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName" />
```

Comment: @nasty What exactly you need to achieve?

Comment: I want to show the placeholder in the field but if you type something it deosnt replace what you have written with the placeholder

Comment: @nasty So Initial input field will be with placeholder and then if you write something it will remove placeholder value and so on, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149446/discussion-between-yogen-darji-and-nasty).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `focusin` and `focusout`:

```js
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location2"]
];

$.each(inputTextIDs, function(i, v) {
  $(v[0]).val(v[1]).focusin(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == v[1]) {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }).focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).val(v[1]);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hotelLocaiton" />
<input id="agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName" />
```

Comment: This still clears the text when I click into the input field after typing my message. So, 1) Type something in, Then click inside the input field. This should clear the input field

Comment: Thanks heaps. This is amazing. But for password fields, this shows *** instead of the text "Password".. Is it possible to fix at all?

Comment: Well, if type is `password`, its not possible. Yes, some effort and lines-of-codes can be written to tweak and make it work somehow but only if its really worth. Else, I would recommend not to, as it might not support all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as exactly you want and it also working for password field.

```js
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location2"]

];

$.each(inputTextIDs, function(i, v) {
  var placeholderValue = inputTextIDs[i][1];
  $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(placeholderValue);
  
  if($('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).attr("type")=="password"){
    $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).attr("original-type","password");
    $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).attr("type","text");
  }
  
  $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).on('change', function() {      
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
      $(this).val(placeholderValue);
      
      if($(this).attr("type")=="password"){
        $(this).attr("type","text");
      }
    }
    else{
       if($(this).attr("original-type")=="password"){
        $(this).attr("type","password");
      }
    }
  });

  $('input' + inputTextIDs[i][0]).on('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == placeholderValue) {
      $(this).val('');
      
      if($(this).attr("original-type")=="password"){
        $(this).attr("type","password");
      }
    }   
  }).on('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
      $(this).val(placeholderValue);
      
      if($(this).attr("type")=="password"){
        $(this).attr("type","text");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hotelLocaiton" />
<input id="agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName" type="password" />
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. This is amazing. But for password fields, this shows *** instead of the text "Password".. Is it possible to fix at all?

Comment: I have updated answer to make it work for password as well.

Comment: Thanks. But when I click on the password input field, it changes its `type` to text. Then when I click outside it turns to password again

Comment: You can codesnippet again. When you click on password input field it will stay as password field. when click outside it check for value if value exists other than placeholder then it will stay as password type otherwise it will change to text type. you can check this https://www.screencast.com/t/Kc2nkdvv